# How to preview page when doing javascript developement with Vim

Tags: javascript, vim

I'm learning to do javascript development with Vim
I would like to know how other people do to preview the result of your javascript code
I can of course manually launch and refresh a browser
but there must be an automatic way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use xdotool[1] to automate the "switch focus to browser, hit f5" part. All this is in a shell script, say reload.sh, and I call it from vim by mapping  like this:

```
:nmap <C-L> :!reload.sh<CR>
```

reload.sh (untested, you may need to massage it a bit):

```
#!/bin/sh
WID=`xdotool search "Mozilla Firefox" | head -1`
xdotool windowactivate --sync $WID
xdotool type f5
```

[1] http://www.semicomplete.com/projects/xdotool/